# Does a T test on Excel return a P value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When doing a T-test on Excel is it possible to return a P value?

Comment: Yes that's what TTEST does. If your data is in E6:E8 and F6:F8, then TTEST(E6:E8, F6:F8, 2, 3) will yield the p-value of a two-tailed unequal variance t-test.

Answer (score 1):

The Thunder Chimp has it exactly correct. And FYI, here is the help page for TTEST() from Excel help:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that it returns the p value. I ran into that same problem, so I ported my data to R (because it's a bit more verbose). Indeed, it confirmed it was returning the p value.